# SQL Server bcp command field separate in Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, bcp

**tblMailer**:

```
ID   FinalCluster
1    BTST,Short Term
2    BTST,Long Term
3    BTST,Mid Term
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    @outputstring = 'bcp " SELECT ''ID'', ''FinalCluster'' 
                           union all 
                           SELECT ID, FinalCluster 
                           FROM CRM.[dbo].[tblMailer]" queryout ' + @FileName + ' -c -t, -T -S Mimansa'
```

Query result in Excel file:

```
[A]      [B]                               [C]
ID    FinalCluster
1       BTST                               Short Term
2       BTST                               Long Term
3       BTST                               Mid Term
```

I want query result in Excel file in following way:

```
[A]      [B]                   [C]
ID    FinalCluster
1     BTST,Short Term
2     BTST,Long Term
3     BTST,Mid Term
```

Note: column `B` is separated in two different column in Excel file instead of single field.

Comment: Maybe something like `select ID, '"' + FinalCluster + '"' from CRM.[dbo].[tblMailer]`   https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/creating-csv-files-using-bcp-and-stored-procedures/

Comment: show error invalied column name

Comment: You need to find a way to put quotes around the value in FinalCluster, so when you open the csv output in Excel, it remains as a single field

Comment: A bit off topic but I used to pull my hair out importing extract files into SQL Server now I simply use a power shell script which allows me to import CSV (comma or space/tab delimited) and excel spreadsheets. If you are interested let me know.

Comment: Resoved, select ID, char(34) + FinalCluster + char(34) as FinalCluster from CRM.[dbo].[tblMailer]